# React Native add multiple form onPress button and onchangeText issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I had created Dynamic form in ***React native*** there will button if user click on that button it will add new form above the button. The number of time user click on button it will add that much form. I have made it but I'm facing issue during text change.

The problem is when I start typing in form it first show the value for fraction of second and then get empty

***below is my code*** I tried

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { 
    Text, 
    View,
    TextInput
 } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export class IndentForm extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         indents:[]
        };
      }

      addInput(){
          this.setState({ indents:[...this.state.indents, ""]})
      }

      onTextChange = (event, index) => {
        const { indent } = event.nativeEvent;
          this.state.indents[index] = indent

        this.setState({indent})
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                {
                    this.state.indents.map((indent,index) => {
                        return(
                            <View key={index}>

                            <TextInput  
                                name="indent"
                                style={{height: 40,backgroundColor: 'azure', fontSize: 20}}  
                                placeholder="Type here to translate!"  
                                value={indent}   
                                onChange={(event)=> this.onTextChange(event,index)} 
                             />  
                        </View>
                        )

                    })
                }
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={{ height:30, width:70, backgroundColor:'blue'}}
                    onPress={this.addInput.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>Add Form</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default IndentForm
```

Comment: What value does it shows for fraction of second ?

Comment: @V.Sambor the value i enter

Comment: In the new input or in inputs created before?

Comment: @V.Sambor initially there is no form once i click on button it will add new form first form working properly then when i click on button again to add second form, second form have issue but when i add third form second form work fine and third form gives issue and so on

Comment: any specific reason why you are using `onChange` instead of `onChangeText` ?

Comment: @ShocKwav3_  see this https://snack.expo.io/H1WFN4d7B

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ i want create this web app same in react native https://goshakkk.name/array-form-inputs/

Comment: @chiragprajapati I understand your requirements and I have checked out the code. There are some things being done a bit wrongly. For starters, you are mutating the state directly and then setting a totally different variable in the state. Would you like me to write a easier/clearer working version with some explanation?

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ yeah sure why not it will be helpful if you do that. just take a reference from this what i have to build https://goshakkk.name/array-form-inputs/ in React-Native

Answer (score 1):

I have went through your `snack` and made some changes. here is the final working version:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { 
    Text, 
    View,
    TextInput
 } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export class App extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         formFields:[{value: ''}]
        };
      }

      addInput = () => {
        const existingFormFields = this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))
        const allFormFieldsAfterAddingNew = [...existingFormFields, {value: ''}]

        this.setState({formFields: allFormFieldsAfterAddingNew})
      }

      onTextChange = (text, index) => {
        const existingFormFields = this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))
        let targetField = {...existingFormFields[index]}
        targetField.value = text
        existingFormFields[index] = targetField

        this.setState({formFields: existingFormFields})
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:30}}>
                {
                    this.state.formFields.map((field, index) => {
                        return(
                            <View key={index}>

                            <TextInput  
                                name="indent"
                                style={{height: 40,backgroundColor: 'azure', fontSize: 20}}  
                                placeholder="Type here to translate!"  
                                value={field.value}   
                                onChangeText={(text)=> this.onTextChange(text, index)} 
                             />  
                        </View>
                        )

                    })
                }
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={{ height:30, width:70, backgroundColor:'blue'}}
                    onPress={this.addInput}>
                    <Text>Add Form</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

I have tried to use some useful/contextual names as much as possible for you to understand what is going on. But let us go through the core concept here:

1. Made `addInput` function an arrow function since it is in a class component, arrow function does auto binding and binding may get confusing.
2. You did this `this.setState({indent})` in your snack which means `this.setState({indent: indent})`. Please understand this is creating another state(if not defined before) variable in the state named `indent` and was staying side by side with `indents` with holding the value of the current indent of the TextInput it was called from. In summary, it was holding the indent of the last typed TextInputs indent.
3. `addInput` is basically pushing object to the list of form fields in the state. We are creating a copy/deep cloning the state object before making any change there. Your previous statement `this.state.indents[index] = indent` is highly discouraged. **Never mutate state with out `setState`**. By `this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))` we have first created a copy/clone of the `formFields` array then while returning each item we did `{...fields}` now we are creating a copy/clone of the object in context and returning it. This way, we make sure state does not change accidentally while we work with it's data. At the end, we just add a new entry with empty `value` and update the state with `setState` and we see a new field rendered!
4. For updating each data we are doing the same as you were doing initially in your `snack`. Finding the index and update the value. Please note, the data flow is similar as the previous point. We take deepClone of `formFields`, we take the target from the clone, we update the target then we replace the new value object in the taken clone and set it as the new state. Pretty much similar thing as point 3.

As a suggestion, please checkout and to gain more insights of the ES6 features of JS as well as React's.

Deep cloning can be tricky if you don't know how many level you have in your data. Lodash has very useful function for that: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

You can test the code at expo snack. Let me know in the comments if you are unsure of anything.

Hope it helped you. Cheers!

Comment: hey code is working good but can you do like this in react-native https://goshakkk.name/array-form-inputs/

Comment: Hi, could you tell me which part you are looking for. It's pretty much the same logic as the link you provided. Let me know if you mean something specific

Comment: like the code you have written that have `this.state = { formFields:[] };` but i want `this.state = {name: "",shareholders: [{ name: "" }]  }; `

Comment: If you want to remove a field just doing `formFields.filter((item, index) => index !== targetIndex)` would be sufficient. Assuming `targetIndex` is what you want to delete

Comment: i want a objects which contain first key as name string and second will be FormsFields which is array which have objects of with key name

Comment: can you tell me what the `name` for? I understand you want `shareholders: [{ name: "" }]` to show one pre rendered textfield when the page loads right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197610/discussion-between-shockwav3-and-chirag-prajapati).

Comment: I have `this.state = {companyName: "",shareholders: [{ name: "" , moneyToInvest:""}] };`  as initial state first name is name of company for which i have api to render company name then there will be addShareholder button to add shareholders to that company and shareholders have their name and  moneyToInvest  as input and if there is multiple shareholders then i can add more forms to add more shareholders and at bottom there will be submit button to sumbit the form